# Пропадает переменная из формы HTML

Tags: php, html, форма

Я делаю проект программы долгов. У меня есть библиотека файлов в которую записываются все долги. Я делаю скрипт который редактирует файлы средствами PHP. Вот как выгледит этот скрипт в браузере:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у меня почему-то в этой форме пропадает переменная `$_POST['name']`.

Вот код того как я изменяю файл в файловой библиотеке:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Изменение данных...</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="icon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>

<?php

$file = './Debts/'.$_POST['id'].'.txt';
$f = fopen($file, 'w+');
$r1 = fwrite($f, $_POST['sum'].PHP_EOL);
$r2 = fwrite($f, $_POST['surname'].PHP_EOL);
$r3 = fwrite($f, $_POST['currency'].PHP_EOL);
$r4 = fwrite($f, $_POST['name'].PHP_EOL);
$r5 = fwrite($f, $_POST['from'].PHP_EOL);
$r6 = fwrite($f, $_POST['to'].PHP_EOL);
fclose($f);

if($r1 === FALSE){
    echo 'Поизошла ошибка. Код ошибки W1/CG. Если вы видите это сообщите на указанный e-mail о ошибке. E-mail: alexander@kornienko.ru';
} else {
    if($r2 === FALSE){
        echo 'Поизошла ошибка. Код ошибки W2/CG. Если вы видите это сообщите на указанный e-mail о ошибке. E-mail: alexander@kornienko.ru';
    } else {
        if($r3 === FALSE){
            echo 'Поизошла ошибка. Код ошибки W3/CG. Если вы видите это сообщите на указанный e-mail о ошибке. E-mail: alexander@kornienko.ru';
        } else {
            if($r4 === FALSE){
                echo 'Поизошла ошибка. Код ошибки W4/CG. Если вы видите это сообщите на указанный e-mail о ошибке. E-mail: alexander@kornienko.ru';
            } else {
                if($r5 === FALSE){
                    echo 'Поизошла ошибка. Код ошибки W5/CG. Если вы видите это сообщите на указанный e-mail о ошибке. E-mail: alexander@kornienko.ru';
                } else { 
                    if($r6 === FALSE){
                        echo 'Поизошла ошибка. Код ошибки W6/CG. Если вы видите это сообщите на указанный e-mail о ошибке. E-mail: alexander@kornienko.ru';
                    } else {
                        echo 'Файл отредактирован успешно!';
                        echo '<form action=main.php > <input type=submit value="Вернуться на главную"></form>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

?>

    <form action=chenge.php><input type=submit value=Назад></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот код формы выведенный через `echo`.

```
echo '<form method=POST action=chenger.php>';
echo '<tr><td><input type=text name=id value='.$i.' readonly></td><td><input type=text name=name value='.$arr['0'].'></td><td><input type=text name=surname value='.$arr['1'].'></td><td><input type=sum name=name value='.$arr['3'].'></td><td><input type=text name=currency value='.$arr['2'].'></td><td><input type=date name=from value='.$arr['4'].'></td><td><input type=date name=to value='.$arr['5'].'></td><td><input type=submit value=Изменить></td></tr></form>';
$i++;
```

Массив `$arr` беру с помощью функции `file()` из файла.

Comment: У вас этот код работает вообще? В конце слишком много знаков }

Comment: @paqstd Работает...

Comment: про `else if`, `switch` не слышали?